# AttributeError: vocabulary not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using movie_reviews data and using countvectorizer in it. I want to change it in dictionary for showing the unique words in index as you see the code below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk
cv = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize , stop_words='english')
movie_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(movie_train.data)

movie_train_cv.vocabulary_
```

AttributeError: vocabulary not found.
At last line ,I get the error. Please let me know what is the correct syntax.

I want like that.

```
sents = ['A rose is a rose is a rose is a rose.',
     'Oh, what a fine day it is.',
    "It ain't over till it's over, I tell you!!"]

  #sents turned into sparse vector of word frequency counts
  sents_counts = foovec.fit_transform(sents)
  #foovec now contains vocab dictionary which maps unique words to indexes
  foovec.vocabulary_
```

here is the output of this code:
{'a': 4, 'rose': 14, 'is': 9, '.': 3, 'oh': 12, ',': 2, 'what': 17, 'fine': 7, 'day': 6, 'it': 10, 'ai': 5, "n't": 11, 'over': 13, 'till': 16, "'s": 1, 'i': 8, 'tell': 15, 'you': 18, '!': 0}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `fit_transform` on a `CountVectorizer` returns an array, as discussed in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform).

The `vocabulary_` attribute is on the `CountVectorizer` itself. The returned array does not have a `vocabulary_` attribute.

To access the vocabulary of the `CountVectorizer` after you've created it, simply do the following:

```
vocab = cv.vocabulary_
```

Comment: You can access the vocabulary attribute on the CountVectorizer object itself. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes! it makes sense. But let me show you what I want.

Comment: please check it and help me out

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking